# Javascript Changing URLs based upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, hyperlink, variable-assignment

I am working with the Soundcloud API. A user searches a song or band name and my page returns an output of all the album art associated with each track. I have insert a "play" button for each track; however, the play link (var named "linky") only seems to take on the LAST called track on the page. So EVERY "play" link will only play the last track on the page. How do I make it so that each "play" link will link to its appropriate track?

```
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'xxxxeditedforprivacyxxxx'
  });

  function doSearch() {

    var searchTerm = document.getElementById('search').value;

    // Search soundcloud for artists
    SC.get('/tracks', { q: searchTerm}, function(tracks) {
      for(track in tracks) {

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute("src", (tracks[track]["artwork_url"]));
        var title = tracks[track].title.replace("'", "\\\'").replace("\"", "\\\"");

        var song = document.createElement('div');

        linky = tracks[track].permalink_url;

        img.setAttribute("onclick", "showTrackInfo('" + title + "\\n" + "\\n" + tracks[track].label_name + "\\n\\n" + "(click to close)" + "')"); 



        if (tracks[track]["artwork_url"] == null) {
          console.log(""); } 
          else { 

            var Catalog = document.getElementById('catalog');
            Catalog.appendChild(img);


            $('div#catalog').append('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/rGdvfl7.png" id="play">');

            console.log(linky);

            $('img#play').click(function() {
              $.get(
                'http://soundcloud.com/oembed?' + 
                'url=' + linky + 
                '&format=json&maxheight=296'
                )
              .done(function (response) {
                song.innerHTML = response.html;
                document.getElementById("soundiframe").appendChild(song);
              });
            });
          }


      }
    });
  };
```

My `console.log(linky);`  is showing the appropriate, different URLs for each track. But the play button only wants to play the last track that's pulled. Where am I going wrong? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the closure value `linky`. Since `linky` is a closure value it will have the last assigned value.

The same problem exists for the variable `songs` also, since it is used only within the ajax success callback you can move the creation of the element to the callback

You have mix raw dom manipulation which is not recommended if you are using jquery. I've tried to rewrite the code to use jQuery by removing raw dom manipulation.

Also you were creating some dom elements like `img` and `Catelog` which were never added to the dom so I've removed it

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'xxxxeditedforprivacyxxxx'
});

$(function(){
    $('#catalog').on('click', '.play', function(){
        $.get(
            'http://soundcloud.com/oembed',{
                format:'json',
                maxheight:'296',
                url:$(this).data('linky')
            }
        ).done(function (response) {
            $("#soundiframe").append('<div>' + response.html + '</div>');
        });
    })
})

function doSearch() {

    var searchTerm = document.getElementById('search').value;

    // Search soundcloud for artists
    SC.get('/tracks', { q: searchTerm}, function(tracks) {

        $.each(tracks, function(key, track){
            if (track.artwork_url) {
                $('#catalog').append('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/rGdvfl7.png" class="play" data-linky="' + track.permalink_url + '" />');
            }
        })
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This works, but only for the first song. Any other song I click play for after the first will return the last song always. Might you know why this is happening? Either way I'm really happy to learn about the closure value happening.

Comment: @jenno another problem is you have multiple elements with the id `play` since it is used within a loop